# Build multiple iOS / Android apps with one Flutter code-base?

Tags: flutter

Let's expect we developed a community (with categories, threads, posts, etc.) for a specific target group like developers. This community works quite well and you now want to give designers such a platform too.

Is it possible, to build multiple iOS and Android apps with the same functionality from one Flutter code-base?

Just the colors, backend-URI, app-icon and some trivial stuff like this should be different depending on config-files per "instance".

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Flutter is the best fit for such apps, As Flutter works well with both platforms and also can be scaled to different platforms like Windows and MacOS

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do this.

Main issue would be creating different builds, and some of the app configuration files. But, you should be able to set environment variables when building the apps which would set which app configuration files and settings to use (i.e. app name, id, etc...). You could then use those variables in your app to dynamically change how the app looks.

You can find more info in these two articles:

https://iiro.dev/2018/03/02/separating-build-environments/
https://binary-studio.com/2020/04/17/flutter-2/

Comment: https://medium.com/@angeloavv/easily-build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-flutter-flavorizr-d48cbf956e4